# Unresolved External symbol Time Class

Tags: c++, class, linker

so my error is Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class Time const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVTime@@@Z) referenced in function _main   c:\Users\marklaptop\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\main.obj  ConsoleApplication6

This is confusing because at my school's computer lab everything was working fine and I didn't receive this error. I saved the text and opened it at home and it doesn't work because of a linking error

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Time t1, t2, t3(123456), t4(-5);
    cout << "t1 = " << t1 << '\n';
    cout << "t2 = " << t2 << '\n';
    cout << "t3 = " << t3 << '\n';
    cout << "t4 = " << t4 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

now my header file
    #ifndef TIME_H
    #define TIME_H

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Time {

public:
// constructors
    Time();  //default constructor
    Time(int s); // conversion constructor
    Time(int d, int h, int m, int s); // days, hours, minutes,

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Time& t);

private:
    //member variables
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
};

#endif
```

and finally the time.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

Time::Time()
//default constructor. Initialize everything to start at 0
{
    day = 0;
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}
Time::Time(int s)
{
    if (s < 0)
    {
        day = hour = minute = second = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        second = s;
        day = second / 86400;
        hour = (second / 3600) % 24;
        minute = (second / 60) % 60;
        second = second % 60;
    }
}
Time::Time(int d, int h, int m, int s)
{
    day = d;
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
    if (h < 0){
        h = 0;
    }
    if (d < 0){
        d = 0;
    }
    if (m < 0){
        m = 0;
    }
    if (s < 0)  {
        s = 0;
    }


}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Time& t)
{
    out << t.day << "~";
    if (0 <= t.hour && t.hour <= 10)
    {
        out << "0" << t.hour << ":";
    }
    else
        out << t.hour << ":";

    if (0 <= t.minute && t.minute <= 10)
    {
        out << "0" << t.minute << ":";
    }
    else
        out << t.minute << ":";

    if (0 <= t.second && t.second <= 10)
    {
        out << "0" << t.second;
    }
    else
        out << t.minute;


    return out;

}
```

also, one final question, would anybody be able to help out with an operator overload of the operator>>, I am ok with comparison and addition operators and such but I don't understand how to use the extraction operator.
I was trying
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, const Time& t);
in the header file but couldn't figure out what to write in the function body in the cpp file. Any help would be great

ok so my link problem is solved, and I understand what the extraction operator does. I would put this in the header...

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, const Time& t);
```

and this in time.cpp

```
 istream& operator>>(istream& in, const Time& t)
{
    in >> t.day;
    in >> t.hour;
    in >> t.minute;
    in >> t.second;


    return in;
}
```

the main.cpp test file has this

```
cout << "Enter first Time object (DAYS~HH:MM:SS):  ";
cin >> t1;
```

The user is entering them in the (DAYS~HH:MM:SS) format, so will just saying 
in >> t.day; take in the value that will be at (DAYS), is it that simple?

Comment: this isn't all of the main file either, just what goes with what I have coded so far

Comment: So, the linker says that it sees no piece of code from 'time.cpp'. Probably, you didn't put it in your project, do you? About implementing 'operator>>', it's _your_ homework to do. Start from looking into some standard library headers to figure out which predefined function could help you.

Comment: sorry if it seemed like I was asking for the code, but I just was asking if somebody could help get me started/ explain better to me what it means and is used for so I'm not just looking at code from my book and trying to make it look the same, and yes all 3 were in the project. I created a new one and did the same thing but it worked this time, thanks

Comment: Basically, C++ operator overloading can be used just for anything you want. Pure C operators << and >> are just bitwise shifts, but C++ standard library uses operator<< for output and operator>> for input. So it makes sense to have operator>> reading data from istream, parsing it, and storing new day, hour, minute etc. values in Time() class. To make the things consistent, your operator>> should at least be able to input what your operator<< outputs.